# How to disable "exit status 1" when executing os.Exit(1)

Tags: go

In one of my go projects, I run `os.Exit(1)` and it prints out **exit status 1**. How can I disable this message to be printed?

Comment: @KeithThompson windows. I wanna return non zero code to indicate failure but I don't want to display that message.

Comment: Go binaries don't print anything at exit. Either your shell is printing that message, or you're using `go run`, which is reporting the exit status for you (since the real binary is run as a sub-process)

Comment: @JimB yes, I'm using `go run`! Can you put this as an answer so that I can accept this?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

To disable the message, don't use `go run`.

`go run` is a tool to conveniently compile one or more go files into a temporary location, execute the binary, and clean up. Your executable is run in a sub-process, and the `go` tool is reporting the exit status for you.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful